# Why is it so frowned upon to hardcode assets in my game?

Tags: design

I have seen tutorials like [this one](https://youtu.be/vbo8-sktS-w) about how to import models from assets, instead of having them in your code. What is the purpose of that? Why *not* have them in your code? This also applies to textures. A comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62367933/13709754) of mine says to not do this.

- Isn't it easier to have the data in the source file ready to use instead of having to read it from an external asset?
- Isn't it faster and more efficient to have the data in your program ready to use instead of having to load them from an external resource?

In particular, I don't understand why Minecraft has its model files as JSON assets, that not only have to be loaded at runtime, but also have to be interpreted, because JSON is a text-based format. No wonder Minecraft's loading screen takes a long time.

Comment: How would you even store a 3D model "in code", or a texture? Source code is text. Sure, formats such as .obj are just text as well, but In separate files. Are you talking about procedural generation? Only constructing geometry from primitives?

Comment: @Polygnome I am using C and I would store a 3D model as an array of integers, that represents vertices and the planes connecting them to create faces.

Comment: As long as those resource-files are auto-generated from easily editable sources.

Comment: After reading the answers (all fairly reasonable) and the OP's replies, I got the feeling that the question turned into a "change my mind". OP's is looking for us to convince him why such a practice is frowned upon. It's not like we have to convince others why some practices are "convenient". Whether separating both things is "convenient" or not is something the OP has to figure out by his own. After all, we are biased by the sort of apps we design and implement every day. For many of us, separating assets is convenient. Maybe it doesn't matter in this specific app.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. I think hard-coding is a bad practice, but the OP is right to challenge us to think about why.  And I think there is a lot to be taken from the discussion, even if OP is playing the devils advocate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you are very persistently defending your approach. More power to you, since you are writing your own game and you can do what you want with it :)
This is not what I would be doing, but I like your questions because they challenging some of the fundamentals I rarely think about. So challenge accepted:

> Isn't it easier to have the data in the source file ready to use instead of having to read it from an external asset?

Depends. On one hand it is easier if you don't have to worry about loading files and interpreting file formats.
In cases like hard-coding game copy instead of writing a module that manages it and is reading it from a file, or learning about an existing internationalization system. If you don't worry much about translations or changing the copy in the future, this is a good way to go for simple games.
When it comes to reading images you could store a bitmap as an array in your code, but at some point you might want to use image libraries provide with your framework. When using a framework it is often easier to just use it the way it is most commonly used.
E.g. when I was programming games in Visual Basic I found that actually just displaying bmp files was easier than writing my own graphics routines.
If you are writing your game from scratch in assembly, probably hard-coding is the easiest way to go.

> Isn't it faster and more efficient to have the data already in your program ready to use instead of having to load them from an external resource?

Not really. Taking one of my favorite games kobodeluxe, its binary is around 500k while its collected gamefiles together are 1.7 MB. You werite the game that everything is hardcoded in the binary, so you would end up with a 2.3 MB binary..
The overhead of loading just moved from runtime to load time, since loading the game now takes more time.

> Seriously no wonder Minecraft's loading screen takes long as heck.

The alternative would be to have no loading screen, but just an hourglass and an empty screen, while your OS loads the game binary.

(This isn't a particularly accurate description on operating systems where you can map files directly into memory, but the overall sentiment still is true: It doesn't make total load time faster).

Additionally you might be in a situation where you don't actually need all your game files all the time, but you have different sets of graphics and music that only apply to certain stages. If you put everything in your binary playing just a single level will take more time, since you are loading unnecessary assets.

For bigger games you might be in a situation where the assets are so big that they don't fit in the memory or your storage medium at the same time.

All this doesn't really matter if your game is very simple and you use all of the resources all the time..

Now to your actual question:

> Why is it frowned upon to hardcode assets in my game?

Nobody frowns at your game, as long as they don't have to contribute to it :)
Your approach is simple and simple is fine. If someone tells you not do something it is because we care about you and don't want you to dig a hole for yourself.
Some people here have quite some experience in building software and learned a technique or too, that helps to not have a lot of work later on.
These techniques aren't commandments so take from it what you want and with most architectural patterns they only really pay off if you are doing a bigger project over a long time.
They don't make sense if the following is true:

- You don't plan to make changes on your game later on.
- Your game stays small
- You are and will be the only developers working on your game
- You never plan to sell your game code

**Making changes later on**

If there is a chance that you want to make changes to your program later on, you should aim to design your architecture to make this type of changes easy in the future. Often you don't want to just change one item, but a whole group of items.
For example:

- You have too much noise on your sound files and decide to apply some filters to all of them
- You are translating the game from English to Dutch and now every copy string has to be changed
- You used some offensive symbols in the background textures and now you need to remove them everywhere
- You rename your final boss because you got a cease and desist for infringement
- You have to switch all your audio from mp3 to ogg because of licensing fees.
  In these cases it is much easier if your copy strings are all in one place, or you use sound files instead of hard-coded string all over your code.

This point doesn't really require external files, you could have a class for all your English copy, a package with different classes representing textures and so on. But the general advice is to keep things together that change for the same reason.

**Game gets bigger**

If your game gets bigger you will have problem fitting everything in the binary and memory as already mentioned before.
But there is another problem when testing your game: Let's say you are trying to get some of the textures right and you will take multiple iterations to get it right. If you hard-code everything, changing your texture might force you to rebuild, link and restart your whole game.
Build time can be optimized by clever build scripts and decoupling dependencies, but linking will still take time.

**Non-developers working on your game**

It is easy for you make a model by just adding vertices and edges to arrays in C++ or changing copy by changing Strings in the right place.
If you ever have a copy writer, translator or graphic design working on your game it is easier if you do not require them to read and write C++ too.
Copy writers that also know C++ are just harder to find than copy writers in general.
You could argue that you can make the changes for them, but this will significantly slow your development down, since you become the bottleneck.

**More than one developer**
If you develop a project with more than one person it becomes easier to separate code that can change independently.
If a copy change needs to be done in 30 different files, this change will impact a lot of different developers, you might have merge conflicts or break each others assumptions.
If this change is only happening in one file it is much easier to work on the code independently. Having your code being more modular will also make it easier for new developers to work on your code, as they don't have to understand everything to get started.

**Selling your game**
Some time ago Ken Silverman wrote a game called Ken's Labyrinth. The game itself wasn't especially popular or good, but he the game engine was used for other games like Shadow Warrior, Blood or Duke Nukem 3D.
If he had decided to hard-code every texture and sound file, selling the game engine would have been much harder, since it would have been a challenge for the game developers of Monolith or 3D Realms to build completely new games out of it, for all the reasons I mentioned above.

Again, all these advantages only really come into play when you start working on bigger projects. As it appears to me, you are actually just working on a small game and your team only consists of yourself.
In that case it is up to you, but if you ever want to build bigger games as well, or work in software development professionally I would be open to at least consider some of the techniques used by experienced game developers, since it will take some time to learn and internalize best practices.

Answer (score 5):

The operative principle here is that you're **separating the model's *representation* from its *implementation.***

The *representation* is that which differs among all of the different models you might want to use in your game, namely *all of them.*  No two landscapes are alike.

Conversely, the *implementation* is that code which takes your representation and turns it into a visible landscape, weapon, whatever.

By separating your representations from your implementations this way, it becomes possible to change, for example, your landscape from a forest into an iceberg by simply changing the assets you upload.  In other words, you can change your assets without having to change your code.

If this doesn't sound like a big deal to you, ask yourself why Amazon doesn't just write more code when they get a new customer, instead of storing the new customer in a database.

Comment: But the assets aren't going to change anyways, so why not have them hardcoded?

Comment: Your question was "Why is it so frowned upon."  As usual, the decision is always yours.

Comment: If the assets are part of the source of the executable, that does not in any way imply that they are part of the programmer-editable source-code. Executables often contain at least contain many sections, and one (or more) of them might be "resources".

Comment: "Assets aren't going to change anyways". For most programs that simply isn't true. Just as source code changes because it is iterated upon and improved, assets also change.

Comment: @9694: The assertion that you know for a definitive fact that something isn't going to change is an attitude that is the most prevalent source of bad practice, high technical debt and low code maintainability - all of which is going to massively detract from the quality of your work. No matter the asset, there's always some unforeseeable circumstance that would require you to adjust it. You're not accounting for things beyond your control.

Answer (score 4):

> I am using C and I would store a 3D model as an array of integers, that represents vertices and the planes connecting them to create faces

OK, simple enough. But what happens when you start to add more capability? Are you going to have a color for each pixel too? Are you going to have normals for lighting? Are you going to have UV coordinates for texture mapping? Are you going to have textures? As you add more and more elements, your data structures are going to grow more and more complex.

Let's say you want to have textures, now where do you store those? Surely you aren't planning on storing jpegs in your source code? How do you expect to edit them? How do you expect to keep track of what's what?

Just forget about the high level stuff like models or patching or software engineering for a moment, and just think about trying to wrangle all your game's media.

Surely, you are going to use some kind of image editing software to make your textures or other images, some kind of modeling software to make your models, an audio editor for sound effects, etc. None of those are going to write hex strings into a source code file. So, you're going to have to write tooling to deal with those files.

So, which makes more sense: write something to convert those files into your source code, and have to manage both your code and the files, or just have your code load those files from a file package like a zip like a normal person?

> But the assets aren't going to change anyways, so why not have them hardcoded?

Oh really? Are you sure you're never going to change them, even while developing your game? You're never, ever going to tweak an image, replace a sound effect, or anything?

Last thing to consider: If your goal isn't actual data in the source, but a single executable, there are solutions to that. An example is appending a zip file onto the end of your built binary, then reading the zipped contents from your code.

Comment: If I tweak an image, or change a sound effect, I can change the code to change them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be able to change things such as 3D models or images of your system later, then you need to keep them in some data format which can be edited easily by a 3D modeler like Blender or an image processing tool like Gimp.

Sure, you can take such data and write a conversion tool which encodes the (often binary) data into strings using only the valid characters of your favorite programming language. A common encoding used for this is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

But what do you expect to gain from this? Faster loading times? That usually won't work. The data has to be loaded from a hard disk into RAM anyway, irrespective of whether it is in a separate binary file or directly part of the source code.

Moreover, the CPU will need a little more time to decode the base64 again into a format which can be processed in the usual manner, and the base64 encoding will also require more bytes on disk than the original files.

Or do you want to have all of the resources in one compiled executable file? For this purpose, most compilable programming languages allow binary files to be embedded as resources directly into the code (see [here for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247680/adding-resource-files-to-xcode), for example).

And now you have to manage both:

- the data in its original, editable form, and
- the data in the encoded form.

So what you gain here is only more overhead for no apparent benefit.

Comment: I will not use base64. I will use C's hexadecimal constants in strings, like specified in the StackOverflow question I linked.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand how hexadecimal character constants in C strings work. I want to do this to hide assets from showing package contents and reading speed.

Comment: Why should the assets need any extra-encoding? Resources can be embedded as-is. And there is a small (likely insignificant) saving in not having to find and open separate files. Also, the executable is paged in on-demand nowadays.

Comment: @Deduplicator: tell the OP, not me.

Comment: Looks like the OP is obfuscating the assets. Maybe he's concerned about others accessing and withdrawing these assets. Basically, he's doing what we do many times with Javascript apps. Getting everything into a single resource (the app) in such a way others can not re-use it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me address the question from a different point of view.

> isn't it easier to have the data in the source file ready to use
> instead of having to read it from an external asset?

The question is if it's appropriate.

For many of us, it is. Mainly due to the software we develop. We have found it to be beneficial in most of our developments, overall if those assets change at different times and due to different reasons than the source code<sup>1</sup>. I'm thinking about web apps, but it's easily applicable to desktop and mobile apps too. And I'm sure it's for many other kinds of applications.

Now, whether this's convenient for you, we can not say. It depends on your needs. You are the only in the position to say if your assets are unlikely to change. If you are convinced that they will never (ever) change or you are convinced that they will but at the same time and due to the same reasons than the source code, then don't do it. Keep them in the source code. For convenience or practicality, not by technical reasons.

However, whoever has been developing at least for a year (or even less) knows that the only constant in the SE is change.

Perhaps it's not the code what changes. Maybe it's the asset or maybe its maintenance. Maybe at some point, you realise that you need to automate or ease the edition of the asset. Maybe then, you realise that moving the resource to a different file is convenient and practical because:

- Editing a 3D model with raw arrays of numbers is costly (time/money)
- Not all developers know how to model with arrays
- Not all the 3D designers are developers
- It could be interesting to use tools for its maintenance.
- It's even more interesting to use some of the well-known and supported standards so you can delegate the edition to someone else. Someone who doesn't need to know C.

Separating assets and code is the tactical solution we implement to take forward a given strategy, the one that use to say: *assets may change any time and the application must remain unaware and unaltered due to those changes so both, asset and application, can be managed independently from each other*.

---

<sup>1: At this point, I have to say that the market insists on industrializing the SDLC. As you know, cars are not built from a unique block of steel. The whole process is decomposed in several processes, parts and pieces to finally get them all assembled in the assembly line. And it's done this way because it's proven to be the "best" strategy for the companies. To a degree, this applies to the SDLC too.</sup>

Comment: Regarding your footnote: that principle only remotely applies to SDLC. Imagine what a car factory would look like if material costs were 0, and assembly was nearly instantaneous and free.

Comment: Are you suggesting that SDLC is cost-free and its assembly instantaneous? Because I could not be more disagree.

Comment: Assembly of software is compiling, its marginal cost is nearly 0. Additionally, the marginal cost for another copy of software is also almost 0. Compared to a car, where material cost is significant, and tooling costs, specific to a model are enormous. Software development is a design process, not a manufacturing process.

Comment: We have different points  of view regarding assembly and costs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few advantages to loading assets from separate resource-files instead of embedding them in the executable:

1. Patching is easier as only the assets and/or executable(s) which changed have to be modified/replaced.
2. Using different assets (language/extension/mod) becomes easier.
   The existing assets may even serve as an example for modders.
3. Downloading assets on-demand (or only installing a subset) becomes feasible.

Still, having a single self-contained executable, as long as it isn't too big and containg too much unused stuff, also has its advantages.
You are unlikely to want to execute it from removable media, directly out of an archive, or immediately on downloading though.
It's a game, not a tool, right?

Comment: Why would I download assets on demand? All the assets are the same, and will remain constant.

Comment: Yes, that may be the case for you, for this program. Or so you think. Look at the other reasons too, and in the end you might decide embedding is the way to go. Just, automate embedding the editable source-assets if you do, recreating intermediate files as needed.